# GLM returning negative value for threshold (cut-off)(in R)

Tags: r, glm, dismo

I am working with species distribution modeling with GLM. I have (South America) data for *Caiman crocodilus* species from GBIF (http://www.gbif.org/species/5846514) and bioclimatic data from Worldclim (http://worldclim.org/current). I trying to run GLM in order to model species distribution (with dismo package):

```
modelGLM = pres ~ bioclim_10 + bioclim_11+ bioclim_16 + I(bioclim_16^2) + bioclim_17
GLM <- glm(modelGLM, family=binomial(link=logit), data=PresBackTrainRaw)
projecaoSuitability = predict(predictors, GLM, type='response')
```

Until here, everything looks fine, but when I try to obtain the threshold (cut-off), negative value is returning:

```
library(dismo)
> evaluation=evaluate(p=presencesTest,a=backgroundTest,m=GLM,x=predictors)
> thresholdValues=threshold(evaluation,'spec_sens')  
> thresholdValues    
> [1] -2.578797
```

Since glm output (with type='response') ranges from 0 to 1, a negative threshold does not make sense. Someone can help me see what is wrong?

Comment: are you 100% sure this calculation is being done on the probability scale and not the logit/log-odds scale?

Comment: from `?evaluate` : `evaluate` seems to have an `...` argument for the `predict` . try adding `type='response'`

Comment: Yes! This provided the correct threshold values. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution (provided by  user20650):

Add `type='response'` in `evaluate`:

> library(dismo) 
>   evaluation=evaluate(p=presencesTest,a=backgroundTest,m=GLM,x=predictors,type='response')
>   thresholdValues=threshold(evaluation,'spec_sens')
>   thresholdValues
>   [1] 0.07042211